# Get voice channel id from user id discord.py

Tags: python, discord

My question is how can i get the voice channel id a user is in without that person typing in any chats, if i know the persons user ID.

Example Code:

```
USER_ID = 1234578654

@bot.command()
async def join():
    account = bot.get_user(USER_ID)
    channel = account.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
```

In steps

1. Figure out which channel a user is in with there id
2. join that channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and get the channel by the `member` argument. You can now either use the name or ID of the user.

**Take a look at the following example:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    try:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        if channel: # If user is in a channel
            await channel.connect() # Connect
            await ctx.send("User is connected to a channel, joining...")
        else:
            await ctx.send("I am already connected to a channel.") # If the bot is already connected
    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send("User is not in a channel, can't connect.") # Error message
```

**What did we do?**

- Get the voice channel of `discord.Member`.
- Connect to the channel if the member is in a voice channel.
- Give out an error if the `member` is not connected to a channel.

**To define a user you can use the following function:**

```py
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    try:
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(YourID) # Get the member by ID
        if member:  # If it is the defined member
            await member.voice.channel.connect()  # Connect
            return await ctx.send("User is connected to a channel, joining...")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Not the defined user.")
    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send("The defined user is not in a channel.")  # Error message
```

*For more information you can also look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_members#discord.Client.get_all_members)*

Comment: I already have the id of the user, i dont need to find it but ill give it a go

Comment: With this command you can check it for every `member`. I could also provide an example for your "list".

Comment: I dont completely understand, where in this code does it fetch a user's id

Comment: You have to pass a `member` argument. The command would be `join member/ID`. I do not get what your question is. Are you trying to connect to a channel by passing the user ID/defining the user ID or do you want to get the channel ID a user is connected to?

Comment: I want to connect to a voice channel for a specific user, i already have the user id

Comment: Why do you overcomplicate it that much? This will only connect to one channel then, all the other users will not be able to use the command. I will provide an answer to that too.

Comment: @SomeGuy I added my answer with another example that should work fine.

Comment: what is the `member = get()` where did the get come from

Comment: `from discord.utils import get` - I will add that

Comment: I am passing a valid id but for some reason it still goes to the else statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231234/discussion-between-dominik-and-someguy).

Comment: @SomeGuy I changed my answer again. You can try again and talk to me in chat if it is not working.