# How to get in which voice channel a user is

Tags: python, discord

Not a duplicate of [Get voice channel id from user id discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132135/get-voice-channel-id-from-user-id-discord-py)
I Have tried this

```
auth = message.author
while True:
    print(auth.voice.channel)
```

but after that if I change my voice channel it will still print the voice channel I was in when I sent the message and I want that how to get in which voice channel a user is in currently How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code doesn't update the 'auth' variable
So when calling your loop you print the voice channel from when it was initially called.
I suggest you something like this:

```
id = message.author.id
guild = message.guild
while True:
    channel = guild.get_member(id).voice.channel
    print(channel)
```

and don't forget to add a way to stop your loop !